# Amazon Beanstalk stuck on 100% cpu

Tags: elastic-beanstalk

I've got a micro instance on amazon beanstalk.

Every couple of days it gets stuck on 100% cpu and hangs there until I manually reset it. My question is - why does it get stuck? It's remains in that state long after any user attempts to use it.

Also, is there any simple way to get email notifications when the server enters a warning mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't tell you why the server hits 100%. You need to work out what process is using the CPU. For Linux look at top or atop, for use Windows Task Manager. Once you work out what is using CPU you can look at logs and such.

There is no "warning mode", as such, that I'm aware of on AWS. EC2 instances have an [instance lifecycle](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-lifecycle.html), perhaps you could look at that to clarify what you mean. There is an [autorecover function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-recover.html) on EC2.

[AWS CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) is the system you should be used for monitoring and alerting. It's fairly simple to set it up to alert when your CPU, network bandwidth, disk space, or a host of other things go over thresholds you set. It can monitor your whole AWS infrastructure.

CloudWatch can be default monitor metrics visible to the hypervisor, including CPU. If you want to monitor RAM or disk usage, on Linux, you need to use [these scripts](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-cloudwatch.html) to send the metrics to CW.

Comment: please note that my main enquiry though is why does it remain on a 100% and not go gradually down?

Comment: Read the first paragraph of my answer again. No-one can answer that question for you. It could be anything - an infinite loop in your code for example.

Comment: OK, I'll try and clarify my question then - if there were an infinite loop I'd find it under regular usage, no need for stress testing. I'm not asking why it hit 100% I'm asking why it remained in a 100%.

Comment: You're going to have to work that out yourself, using the methodology I outlined. It's unlikely to be practical for you to provide enough information for anyone to help you with this, and it's a multi-step process.